# What is an alternative to mandatory file locking on macOS?

Tags: macos, locking, finder, file-locking

I'm writing an app for macOS with the primary goal of managing arbitrary user files in a certain manner. 'Management' includes arbitrarily reading/writing/updating these files. Management is **not** internally a discrete event, and may consist of several idle-periods. However, it must appear so to the user.

**Note:** The term 'user' includes any and all **user-activity** (i.e. via Finder) or **user-initiated processes** (i.e. other apps opened by the user; though not running as root, similar to the privileges of my own application).

My app does not store these files in an owned container (e.g. sandboxed app container), but rather runs continuously in the background keeping track of these files, monitoring for changes and managing them as necessary.

The duration of this 'management' may vary from a few milliseconds to a few hours.

I'm trying to write a construct (i.e. `class` / `struct`) to encapsulate references to these 'hot' files (i.e. files under management). During management, the user **must not** be capable of reading/writing-to/deleting these files, unless the app is explicitly quit (through normal quit / forced quit, regardless).

Is there any way I can "lock" a file, as to prevent user reading/writing/updating and/or even modification of permissions?

Here are two possible solutions:

- Copy the file to an undisclosed location, manage it, and overwrite the old file. This is undesirable for multiple reasons: copying is expensive and impractical for large files, user is not explicitly aware of management, does nothing to prevent other processes from seeing the file as "free".
- Modify file permissions. I'm not sure if this is even possible (please let me know *in detail* if it is!), but if my process could modify file permissions as to prevent user-access, it would solve the essence my problem. However, if anything were to prevent my app from 'unlocking' these files (be it through a crash/force-quit etc.), it would leave the files inaccessible to the user.

A third, though not really a solution, would be to simply not attempt to 'lock' any of these files. I could just monitor the files continuously, and alert the user of any failure. I really don't want to do this, hence the question.

The second solution seems quite promising. I can't, however, find any high-level APIs that let me interface with the file ACLs (access-control-lists). I'm not even sure whether I'm correct in my understanding of how it would work, so feel free to build upon that thought and turn it into a concrete answer.

I'm also curious as to how Finder seems to know whether files are being used by other processes. Again, I think I know but I'm not entirely sure, so better ask it here with the main question.